# How to implement Google Login in a WkWebView switching to SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, authentication, mobile, webview, google-signin

I have an `iOS App` that basically runs a mobile website using a `WkWebView`. In the mobile website users can **sign in** using a Google account.

Due to the fact that [google will not allow WebViews to use Google Sign in](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) anymore, how can i login my users?

I think of two solutions:

1. Intercept the google login URL (account.google.com/) and open a `SFSafariViewController` and then somehow get the callback in my WkWebView?

   2. Intercept the google login URL and use a `Google Sign in SDK` which relays on the `SFsafariViewController` but will give me only an **userToken** which i would have to send to my website and authenticate the user in the server side.

Is there an easy way to authenticate the user without dealing with the tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

Basically when the WkWebkit launches the `account.google.com`  URL i intercept it and launch the Google native library for sign in, which launches a `SFSafariViewController` (in iOS 9+, falls back to a WebView in previous versions).
When the user finishes logginng in , i get a URL call to my app which i handle in the app delegate and get the User information.

In the user object, there comes a serverAuthcode which is the one i need to send to my backend server for it to authenticate the google user. (I basically recreate the oauth callback URL that the server expects)

Comment: How did you intercept the account.google.com url?